# highcharts is not showing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new at web developer. I created a simpe website to showing a char but I have a problem. My problem is when i'm using highcharts to display all of my data. My highcharts is not showing. I have searched in another articles but I still don't get solution of my problem.

I have checked my browser console, and I got error like this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE1WA.png)

This is my index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extension/Highcharts/code/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extension/Highcharts/code/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extension/Highcharts/code/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extension/Highcharts/code/js/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Dashboard'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Fatmawati', 'Tebet', 'Bekasi', 'TB Simatupang', 'Senen'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Orang',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Peserta',
            data: [20, 15, 30, 67, 47]
        }]
    });
</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Absensi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix this? I'm using offline highcharts and i have downloaded highcharts files and paste them in my folder.

Any help is very useful for me.

**UPDATE**

I did some mistake when import js file from my folder and it is working now. Thanks for all helps.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Comment: move all of your script tags just before ending the body tag.

Comment: It works when entered into a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/nrdc4ky5/

Comment: I have moved all of my scripts but i still get same error @TahaPaksu

Comment: do you moved them to the bottom of the `div#container2` ?

Comment: @MarcelRuben Execute your code when the DOM finished loading.

Comment: @ewolden, I have created my code from jsfiddle and it works when I run at there but when I copy all of codes from there to my project, it gives me error 13

Comment: @TahaPaksu when i moved them to the bottom of the div#container2, it showing black image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to highcharts error, Highcharts is unable to find HTML element to render. You're calling the function before the DOM is initialised. Try putting your `script` tag after the HTML body.

Highcharts error: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Comment: It is showing black images if i put my script tag after HTML body

Comment: Then the problem is not with highcharts.

Comment: Can you create a new jsfiddle with these changes. Try adding JS inside HTML section of the jsfiddle.

Comment: i have moved my js to HTML section of the jsfiddle and it is working fine